# For-loop which should print out ArrayList attribute and other ArrayList Attribute

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to print out attribute from two different ArrayLists in the same syso. Cant get it to work and killed myself finding out why it doesnt

```
    for (int i = 0; i < resultlist.size(); i++) {
        Athlete matched = null;
        Result res = resultlist.get(i);
        for (int x = 0; x < resultlist.size(); x++) {
            Athlete del = athletes.get(i);
            if (res.compStartNumber() == del.startNumber()) {
                matched = del;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(matched.surName() + " " + matched.lastName() + " has result: " + res.resultValue());
    }
```

Works fine just printing out the resultValue for each Result but cant get it to work with the name aswell. So my question is: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the code that you use for the name. Possibly your problem is the issue addressed in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: Are you comparing `Strings` with `==`?

Comment: You iterate twice on the same list. The variable `x` is not used anywhere.

Comment: You should iterate second loop with `x < athletes.size();` and use `x` on `athletes.get(x)`

Comment: In fact, you should use foreach loops, which would prevent all these bugs from occurring. And you should also use a Map instead of a list, to avoid having an O(n^2) algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change

```
for (int x = 0; x < resultlist.size(); x++) {
    Athlete del = athletes.get(i);
    ...
```

to

```
for (int x = 0; x < athletes.size(); x++) {
    Athlete del = athletes.get(x);
    ...
```

so as to loop through the `athletes` arraylist correctly, since the 2 arraylists are probably not the same `size`. Also, this way you would scan all the athletes for each `Result`.